# Swift3 iOS - How to make UITapGestureRecognizer trigger function

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, swift3

I am trying to add a `UITapGesture` to a UIButton so it will trigger a function when tapped. I am using `Swift 3` and is getting some error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SwiftRunner.ViewController tapBlurButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x149e07610'

This is roughly what I have:

```
// Swift 3
import UIKit
class ViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var qsBlurButton: UIButton!       

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("tapBlurButton")))
      qsBlurButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
   }

   func tapBlurButton(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      print("Please Help!")
   }
}
```

Comment: if you want to trigger a function using UIButton then you can also use qsBlurButton.addTarget(target: self, action: ":FuncName", forControlEvents: TouchUpInside)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

From your code you are using swift 3.0 so change your `selector` syntax like this

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))
```

and Your function like this

```
func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Please Help!")
}
```

**Edit:**

Not idea that you are using button with tap gesture, instead of that use inbuilt method `addTarget` for button no need to create tap gesture for it like this

```
qsBlurButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Please Help!")
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that but I am still getting the same error. Also getting the warning "No method declared with Objective-C selector 'tapBlurButton:'"

Comment: @Sebbe you need to put the @objc attribute on your selector method. `@objc func tapBlurButton() ....`

Comment: Try to change your function declaration with my one.

Comment: Now I got it working! The edit version was the correct solution! Ty!

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for the new Swift 3.0 selector syntax for two days.

Comment: @Nirav D Hi,bro, how can you get 17.9k use only 6 monthes?

Comment: @NiravD Thanks! I was just trying to get this to work with Swift 3!

Comment: @RKosamia Does i know you ? What you want to send ?

Comment: @NiravD Have some questions , iOS related so wanted to discuss through email.

Comment: @RKosamia Ask question here on SO and give me link here in comment, if I have solution will post one

Answer (score 10):

To add a gesture recognizer you have to create one indicating which function it will call:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapFrom(recognizer:)))
```

Then add it to the element you need. (You are using a button, and as others have explained buttons have their native 'addTarget' methods)

For explanation purposes imagine you want to add it to an UIView:

```
self.someView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

And don't forget that some elements are "not user interactive" by default so you might have to change that property too:

```
self.someView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

In **Swift 4** the function needs the @objc declaration:

```
@objc func handleTapFrom(recognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    // Some code...
}
```

Comment: In Swift 4 the function needs the @objc declaration. Why?

Comment: Because in Swift 3 it was "inferred" automatically. However in Swift 4 its not anymore. The @objc is used to expose methods to the Objective-C runtime. This function is called through the use of a "selector" which is an Objective-C feature, thus you have to expose it with this keyword.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**

In the case where the `func` for the selector looks like this (note: it doesn't have a _):

```
func tapBlurButton(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  print("Please Help!")
}
```

Then the selector looks like this:

```
#selector(self.tapBlurButton(sender:))
```

So the final code for the selector is this:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(sender:)))
```

If you do not specify that the first parameter has `_`, then you need to use the full name of the first parameter.