# Tap gesture coming back with Error

Tags: swift3, xcode8, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap

I am trying to get the tap gesture to print a line but it keeps coming back with an error that says:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

I have linked the image to the tap outlet and there are no other bad connections.

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("likeTapped:"))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    likeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    likeImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

 func likeTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("yess called")
}
```

Has anyone else had this and is there a solution

Answer (score 1):

was able to fix it thanks to this post.

[How to make UITapGestureRecognizer trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829151/swift3-ios-how-to-make-uitapgesturerecognizer-trigger-function)

I changed my code to this:

```
  likeImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.likeTapped(_:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    likeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

 func likeTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("yess called")
    }
```